# Convert string in pandas dataframe to integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column for number of reviews the dataframe column is listed in this format

```
816 ratings
1,139 ratings
5 ratings
22,3456 ratings
```

Id like to convert this to an integer so I can sort the dataframe. My output should be

```
816
1139
5
223456
```

I tried

```
df=df['num_reviews'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
df
```

however this converted everything after the comma into a decimal. (i.e. 22,3456 returns 22.0)
and using .astype(int) gave me errors due to fields having NaN

Comment: `df=df['num_reviews'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').astype(int)`?

Comment: `.astype(int)` float returns decimal values

Comment: when i use that i get this following error "cannot convert float NaN to integer" your code worked however if i use float so thank you! I just need to be able to sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['num_reviews'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').replace('','0').astype(float)
```

Test case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'num_reviews': ["816 ratings", "1,139 ratings", 
                    "5 ratings", "no ratings", "22,3456 ratings"]
})
print (df['num_reviews'].str.replace(r'\D+', '').replace('','0').astype(float))
```

Output:

```
0       816.0
1      1139.0
2         5.0
3         0.0
4    223456.0
```